# Level a concrete pour 11' x 14'

Tags: repair, concrete, flooring

How best to level a concrete pour enough to finish with engineered floor planks.  The new pour adjoins an existing pour on two sides and is 1/2" to 1 1/2" out of level in places.

The highest imperfections occur at places where existing walls were removed and current flooring needs to extend out.

Contractor did not supervise his cement subcontractor.  Walls were still up at time of pour. He attempted to grind out the differences but was not successful.
It's an open area with two flooring types already in place. Adding a third would not be advisable and only 1 of 2 existing flooring types  is still available.

Comment: If you hired a contractor who then hired sub-contractors then the the contractor is responsible to make it right and it sounds like it needs to be removed and done properly WITH SUPERVISION.

Comment: I'm certain you are correct I just don't the  "want to" try and hold someone accountable.  I'm 70, single, very disappointed. Hoping to be able to get a step by step process/idea I could do on my ownor tell a contractor to follow.